# Tesseract output changing, adding, and removing numbers from very clear image

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am working on a program that uses a webcam to read constantly changing digits off of a screen using pytesseract (long story). It takes an image of the whole screen, then cuts out each number needed to be recorded (there are 23 of them) using predetermined coordinates stored in the list called 'roi'. There are some other steps but this is the most important part. Currently it is adding, deleting, and changing numbers constantly, but not *consistently*. Here are some examples:

**It reads this incorrectly as '32.0'**
[image: 1]

**It reads this correctly as '52.0'**
[image: 2]

**It reads this incorrectly as '39.3'**
[image: 3]

**It reads this incorrectly as '2499.1'**
[image: 4]

These images have already been processed using OpenCV, and it's what all the images in the roi set look like. Based on other answers, I have binarized it, tried to clean up the edges, and put a white border around the image (see code).

This program reads the screen every 30 seconds, sometimes getting it right, other times getting it wrong. Many times it likes change 5s into 3s, 3s into 5s, and 5s into 9s. Sometimes it just misses or adds digits altogether. Below is my code for processing the images.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = #tesseract file path
scale = 1.4
img = cv2.imread(#image file path#)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.rotate(img, cv2.ROTATE_180)
width = int(img.shape[1] / scale)
height = int(img.shape[0] / scale)
dim = (width, height)
img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)                                    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

myData = []
cong = r'--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=+0123456789.-'

for x,r in enumerate(roi):                                                                 
    imgCrop = img[r[0][1]:r[1][1], r[0][0]:r[1][0]]        
    scalebig = 0.2
    wid = int(imgCrop.shape[1] / scalebig)
    hei = int(imgCrop.shape[0] / scalebig)
    newdims = (wid, hei)
    imgCrop = cv2.resize(imgCrop, newdims)

    imgCrop = cv2.threshold(imgCrop,155,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))                              
    imgCrop = cv2.morphologyEx(imgCrop, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel2, iterations=2)

    value = [255,255,255]
    imgCrop = cv2.copyMakeBorder(imgCrop, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, value = value)

    datapoint = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgCrop, lang='eng', config=cong)
    myData.append(datapoint)
```

The output is the pictures I linked above.

I have looked into fine tuning it, but I have a Windows machine and I can't seem to find a good tutorial. I am not a programmer by trade, I spent 2 months teaching myself Python to do this, but the machine learning aspect of Tesseract has me spinning, and I don't know how else to fix remarkably inconsistent readings. If you need any further info please ask and I'll be happy to tell you.

Edit: Added some more incorrectly read images for reference

Comment: Please post 1-2 images that failed. Please to post original image (just roi) - maybe there could be better preprocessing suggestion.  Also you can try to use different `psm` e.g. 7 or 8 (line/word).

Comment: @user898678 I unfortunately cannot post the full image due to company IP, but because there is other text and numbers on the screen, this seems like the best way to isolate only the numbers that I need. I will post a couple more images that were read incorrectly. I have tried changing the PSM setting to several other options with similar/worse results.

Comment: @nathancy I have tried the suggestions in that post with similar results to what I am getting now.

Comment: I wrote: original image (just roi). roi = region of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you use the right image format (jpeg is the wrong format for OCR)
2. In the case of the tesseract LSTM engine make sure the letter size is not bigger than 35 points.

With tesseract best_tessdata I got these results:

[image]

```
tesseract 593_small.png -
59.3
```

[image]

```
tesseract 520_small.png -
52.0
```

[image]

```
tesseract 2491_small.png -
249.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know it needed to be less than 35pt. May I ask what size you scaled the images to? I tried scaling mine down by keeping the original image size, and it made things much worse, so I'm thinking I'll have to enlarge them to do the preprocessing, then shrink them again to read them with tesseract, but I'm not sure what size to go down to. Which tess_best traindata you're using/where did you get it? Right now I am using eng.traindata from [this Github page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best). I am using .bmp for the images now, should I switch to .png?

Comment: I downscaled it in infranview with a setting about expecting height (+ border) - it was just a guess... IMO everything between 22-35 pt should work without problem (maybe even smaller). I prefer a format that is able to store dpi information (300 for letter size 22-35) - I am not sure if bmp can do it.

Comment: Downscaling the images to that size seemed to help a little, but I am still unable to get consistent results. I realize it won't be 100% perfect but especially the 249.1 I cannot get to read correctly. Making the images too small results in that one being correct more often, but several other numbers in the roi that were initially correct wrong, and vice versa (I unfortunately cannot include images in comments or I would show you). I will mark your answer as best but I am still hoping for more ways to improve my output.